# loop goes on infinitely when i want it to stop in random color generator game

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a simple script to output a random color and i want the user to choose how many random colors they want but it produces infinite colors.
I have only started python and it would be very appreciated if someone could help me even though it is an indentation problem.
Here is the code:

```
import random

g = 0
a = input("How many random colors would you like? ")
if not a.isdigit():
    print("Please enter a number next time")
    quit()
while True:
    lister = "Purple", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Lime", "Yellow", "White", "Black", "Maroon", "Aqua", "Pink", "Teal", "Grey", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze", "Fuchsia", "Magenta", "Violet", "Beige", "Indigo"
    z = random.choice(lister)
    print("Your color is: " + str(z))
    g += 1
    if g == a:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the logic, or as a simple workaround in your logic do this

```py
if g == a:
```

change this to

```py
if g == int(a):
```

> It's looping infinitely because the `break` logic doesn't work since you are comparing an **integer**(i.e. the variable "g") with a **string**(i.e. the variable "a").

Comment: Oh thanks so much it now works i will accept your answer now